# Call a method when you select item in a listview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What event should I use if I want to do something when I select one item in a listview? I am working in C# and Visual Studio using windows forms.

I have tried this:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = "hi";
}
```

But it wont set the text to "hi", is there some kind of option in the designer that you have to enable or disable?

Answer (score 0):

Is the PostBack property of the ListView set to true? Set a break point on the listView1_SelectedIndexChanged method to see if you are getting there at all.

Comment: i cant find a postback property, i when trough all the properties for the listview alphabetically :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in mvvm you can define a binding in the list view named "SelectedItem", And then a prop in the view model.

now every time you press a list item the prop will get triggered so you can call a method or command.

[image]